# Properly create dictionary of objects/classes while maintaining their documentation

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

If I have a class `listView` that has documentation and I put it in a dictionary:

```js
/** Handles list models */
class listView{}

const views = { list: listView }
```

Then the property/key `list` doesn't have any documentation or intellisense. Is there a way for me to have it show `parentView`'s documentation without copying it?

Edit: One way that can work is to define the class within the object:

```js
const views = {
    /** Handles list models */
    list: class{ }
}
```

But if a better solution exists, please let me know.

Comment: `class listView = {}` I think `=` is a syntax error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox you're right. Fixed

Comment: Since `views` is another object, you'll need to give its properties types

Comment: I found that they correctly capture the property types `list: typeof listView` But, I want to somehow copy over the documentation `Handles list models` to the property. JSdoc tags like `@borrows` haven't been working.